# strlen, rand and substr in PhP

Tags: php, random, substr, strlen

```
<?php
    $name = "Freddy";
    $len = strlen($name);
    $rand = rand(0, $len - 1);
    echo substr($name ,$rand, $rand - 1);
?>
```

The php code is supposed to echo only one character of the name(Using strlen, rand and substr) ,yet that only happens sometimes. I believe this is a problem with the variable $rand, yet after two days of amateur code staring, I am not so sure. help would be greatly appreciated

As I understand it:

- $name = "Freddy"
- $len = 5
- $rand = 0-4

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter of [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is the length of the string, so it should be 1:

```
$name = "Freddy";
$len = strlen($name);
$rand = rand(0, $len - 1);
echo substr($name ,$rand, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = "Freddy";
$len = strlen($name);
$rand = rand(0, $len - 1);
echo $name{$rand};
```

Use the string character offset for this `$string{#}`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't simply do this?

```
$name = "Freddy";
$len = strlen($name);
$rand = rand(0, $len - 1);
echo $name[$rand];
```

array indexes?